# NullPointerException - Working with Location in Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I have unexpectedly received the following NullPointer Exception error while trying to run the application.

```
09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 4751
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751): java.lang.NullPointerException
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at com.dooba.beta.Fragment1.setConversationsList(Fragment1.java:154)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at com.dooba.beta.Fragment1.onActivityCreated(Fragment1.java:97)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1468)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:931)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1011)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:880)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1374)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    09-22 20:22:49.981: E/AndroidRuntime(4751):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Below is what line 154 indicates, and I am assuming a similar issue should arise for line 155.

```
    Location ln;
    Location lt;
    double longi=lt.getLongitude();
    double lati=ln.getLatitude();

    ParseGeoPoint point = new ParseGeoPoint(lati, longi); 
    query.whereWithinKilometers("location", point, 100);
```

Essentially I am trying to retrieve a user based around various criteria, and in this case its the location that is causing an issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Update:

```
   Location location = new Location(""); // location
                    double lati; // latitude
                    double longi; // longitude
                    lati = location.getLatitude();
                    longi = location.getLongitude();


                    ParseGeoPoint point = new ParseGeoPoint(lati, longi); 
                    query.whereWithinKilometers("location", point, 100);
```

Update 2:

I have managed to grab the user latitude and longitude using:

```
@Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location userLocation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            double lati = userLocation.getLatitude();
            double longi = userLocation.getLongitude();

            }
```

Problem is incorporating this into the current fragment code is problematic.

```
private void setConversationsList() {
        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();


        // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

        // query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

        query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                .getObjectId());

        query.setLimit(1);


        Location location = new Location(""); // location
        double lati; // latitude
        double longi; // longitude
        lati = location.getLatitude();
        longi = location.getLongitude();


        ParseGeoPoint point = new ParseGeoPoint(57, -122); 
        query.whereWithinKilometers("location", point, 1113);


        query.orderByDescending("Name");

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query1 = ParseUser.getQuery();
```

Comment: Try logging what `lt` is before you get its longitude.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Could you kindly elaborate?

Comment: When do you set `lt`? You define `Location lt;` but I don't see you setting `lt = blahblahblah;` anywhere.

Comment: thats the issue I am not sure what to initialize it as all I want to grab the latitude and longitude information of the user

Comment: way too much code here.

Comment: I've reduce the amount of the code. only shown whats relevant

Comment: Here's how you initialize your location: [link](https://www.google.rs/search?q=Android+getting+Location&oq=Android+getting+Location&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60l2j0l2.9794j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 4):

After ctrl-f'ing code i didnt find any assignment of lt ('lt=', 'lt ' or '(lt)'). You should probably initialize variable before using it. 
Also, you should cut irrelevant parts of code so people wouldnt have to read through roughly 200-300 lines of code that have nothing to do with your problem.

You seem to lack basic knowledge of field/variable initialization but anyway, I recently did something similar, you can view code here: https://github.com/dbarwacz/Beton

Comment: I agree not all of the code posted is relevant, and I quickly adjust my post, and thats the issue I am not sure what to initialize it as all I want to grab the latitude and longitude information of the user

Comment: Ok, now I see. You subscribe to location updates but you dont use them! Check google maps project template from android studio (or different google example code) for how do properly request location updates. EDIT: http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have updated my initial post. It seems fine in eclipse, but for some reason the result is not being displayed.

Comment: Did you check link I provided you with? Now you will not get NullPointerException from lati = location.getLatitude() but will get IllegalStateException or NullPointers from ParseGeoPoint point = new ParseGeoPoint(lati, longi); (as lati reference to empty data). You have to get location from relevant source (either google play services or locationprovider)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I've look into the documentation and made some progress. I have included update 2 under my initial post.